# Passing data from one custom uitableviewcell to another using Delegates in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Okay so I'm having a UIPicker custom cell and I would like to pass the selected item on "didSelectRow" to another custom cell, I tried doing this with Delegates but the problem is I can't set the delegate as the receiver custom cell(to the one that I want to receive the data), so.. here's my code:

UIPickerView Cell:

```
import UIKit

protocol AlbumsPickerCellDelegate {
    func didSelectedAlbum(_ selectedAlbum: String)
}

class AlbumsPickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//    var indexPath: IndexPath!

    @IBOutlet var albumsPicker: UIPickerView!
    
    
    var pickerData = ["Album1", "Album2", "Album3"]
    var albumsPickerCellDelegate:  AlbumsPickerCellDelegate?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.albumsPicker.delegate = self
        self.albumsPicker.dataSource = self
    }

    
    
    class func cellHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 162.0
    }
    
    
}

extension AlbumsPickerTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(pickerData[row])
        //TODO: Pass the selected data to the albumCell to update the label:
        let selectedAlbumOption = pickerData[row]
        print("Selected Item: \(selectedAlbumOption)")
        
        if let delegate = albumsPickerCellDelegate {
            delegate.didSelectedAlbum(selectedAlbumOption)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

The other custom cell(that I want the data to pass to):

```
import UIKit


class AlbumCell: UITableViewCell, AlbumsPickerCellDelegate {
    func didSelectedAlbum(_ selectedAlbum: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.chosenAlbumLabel.text = selectedAlbum
        }
    }
    
    
    

    
    @IBOutlet var albumTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var chosenAlbumLabel: UILabel!
    
    var albumsPickerTableViewCell = AlbumsPickerTableViewCell()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        albumsPickerTableViewCell.albumsPickerCellDelegate = self
    }

    
    func configureCell(choosenAlbum: String) {
//        albumTitleLabel.text = text
        chosenAlbumLabel.text = choosenAlbum
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Rather than making `AlbumCell` a delegate, make your `UITableView` or `UITableViewController` the delegate, so when user picks a image your tableView/viewController gets to know, it can easily get `AlbumCell` using `cellforRowAtIndexPath` and update its content or reload that specifc cell using `reloadRows(at indexPath`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari to basically to pass the data to the UITableViewController and update the uilabel there? instead of passing it to the custom cell? :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari is right, instead of making one to one communication between cells, get a call back from cell (PickerCell) to your view controller (view controller that has both the cells) and pass the information to your other desired cell (AlbumCell) .

Comment: @rana5ohaib ye but the thing is if I set my tableViewController as the delegate I need to implement the function if the protocol inside the controller and then what..?(if needed I will post my UITableViewController)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because in `AlbumCell` you create another instance of `AlbumsPickerTableViewCell` and use it for delegation.

Generally speaking, implementing a delegate from one cell to another doesn't feel right. You can quickly find yourself in the situation when you need the value from the first cell in the controller and have no way of obtaining it. Also, a strange behaviour can occur if those cells are going to be reused by table view.

In your case, it worth making `UIViewController` which contains `UITableView` a delegate of `AlbumsPickerTableViewCell`, and when it gets called from the cell, pass data into `AlbumCell`.

Also, don't forget that references to the delegate should be `weak` to prevent strong reference cycle.

Comment: First thank you for the comment :) second, I do have a UITableViewController but once I set the AlbumsPicker delegate as self(UITableViewController) I need to implement the function of the protocol inside the UITableViewController,  or u meant to pass the data to AlbumCell with delegates?

Comment: That's true, `UITableViewController` have to conform to `AlbumsPickerCellDelegate` protocol and therefore implement it's required methods. Best practice here is to write an extension for  `UITableViewController`. And to set the delegate for the cell, you have to do it in `cellForRowAt` method when you prepare the cell, just assign `self` to the delegate property of the cell

Comment: I see so basically my UITableViewController is going to become the central controller who shares the data across the cells :) thanks for the help mate, and be safe!.